# How to change default Tizen Web UI appearance like scroller overscroll and the time picker?

Tags: themes, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm new to Tizen development, and I wanted to change the default UI appearances, such as the overscroll, i.e. the effect when you scroll something but the content reaches its edges, and I tried to modify the scroller images, such as this one (`scrollbar-bouncing-effect-left.png`):

[image: scrollbar-bouncing-effect-left.png]

They are located on the `lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/images` folder on every new project.

However, even if I modify that file, there is no effect on my application. The original overscroll effects are still shown.

Moreover, if the `lib/tau` folder is removed, the app still runs. It seems to use the system's tau library instead of those bundled in the app.

This is also the case when modifying other images.

Do you have any idea how to style the default UI widgets?

Comment: Are you debugging on the emulator or real device?

Answer (score 1):

Style of overscroll or date/time picker widgets are defined in WebKit which runs Web applications on Tizen. You can not change this in easy way.

Only way to change overscroll effect is disabled scrolling and insert script to process own scrolling with your effects.

Similar situation is with date/time picker. You can hide default element and create own widget and style it yourself.

Comment: how can scrolling be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app in debug mode and use the [remote inspector](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/ide_sdk_tools/web_inspector.htm) to find out the exact location from which the library is loaded. You can also look for HTML elements responsible for creating the overscroll effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to to this. Tau (God damn it), is based on the jQuery mobile. To be honest, there is encapsulated jQuery inside Tau. I would try to get rid of tau and attach jQuery mobile as well. With my own styles.